# AJAX works based on geographical location?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a site that calls AJAX. It works at my office, where I made it (that is, on many people's computers, on different systems and browsers, not just mine) and it worked from one outside computer (a friend of mine who lives about 10 min from the office). The AJAX fails, however, on every other outside computer. If I try it at home, or another friend of mine tries it at his home, it doesn't work (we live far away from the office). It is a very simple AJAX call using jquery.

```
$(destination).load(url);
```

I checked it with Firebug Console and found this

the AJAX call is listed as

```
GET (url) 200 OK
```

when it works AND when it doesn't work, except that when it doesn't work, its in red and there is an 'X' icon in between the OK and the 152ms(or however long it took).

Params tab - are the same whether it works or not

Headers tab - when it works, the 'request headers' section shows:

```
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Cookie  PHPSESSID=*******
```

But when it doesn't work, these lines are absent but instead there is a line for 'Origin' (which just has the main sites URL in it).

Response/HTML tabs - are empty when it doesn't work.

As I said, I've tested for browsers, computers, Mac, Pc etc and it all works at the office, but not anywhere far away. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I created a test page to separate out the code. The test page worked briefly, then stopped working (which bewilders me). So I now think that my code has an error, but that the error is somehow overlooked by browsers when it happens to work (the original still works in the office, while the test doesn't).

The test page should have 'Worked!' pop up when the 'test' link is clicked. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$call = $_GET['call'];
echo $call;
if($call == 'yes') //check for call
{
    echo 'Worked!';
    exit(); 
}
?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function callAjax(call){
var dest = "#result";
var url = "http://www.test/page/url.php";
var query = "?call="+call;   //turn call into a query string
url = url+query;   //Add querystring to url
$(dest).load(url);   //make the call
}
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:callAjax('yes')">test</a>
<div id="result"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to load ? (if it's not a secret)

Comment: @florian The page I'm loading works fine, even from home (they work if I go to them directly instead of doing the AJAX call). It's a simple listing of some database info. I'm certain the problem has to do with there not being an XMLHttpRequest in the request headers, but I have no idea why that's the case.

Comment: Does `url` look like `http://www.example.com/page`, `/page`, or `page`?

Comment: @icktoofay it is an absolute url. I just put up some code in an edit

Comment: @icktoofay Thanks! Your question led me to the answer. See my solution below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with using the absolute path for the url. It matters to the code whether or not 'www' is in the address bar. So, if you go to the page with 'www' in the address bar, but it isn't in the code url (or vice-versa), it won't work.

The reason it didn't work at some peoples computers is because when they accessed the page, those people didn't put in the 'www' and their address bar didn't match the code url.

Thanks to icktoofay for putting me on the right path to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do to try to target the "bug".

- (if possible) test the Ajax request aside of your project. Make an independant (freshly downloaded jquery.js file) page in your project that loads the expected content and see if it works. In this case the "bug" is relative to your project itself.
- I figured out that I don't have an XmlHttpRequest in the header when the URL doesn't match the host I'm loading the URL from. (for instance trying to load the google.com page). Check that you're not doing crossdomain requests. (I don't think so since it works at your friend's)

[The extreme one]

- I don't know what kind of project it is (public or not) but I already worked on a project where the database access was restricted to certain IP addresses. IP addresses in a given area are similar, so maybe it works fine at your friend's because he lives close to your office and not at your home because IP addresses are too different.

I'm not sure that any of the propositions above could be the solution to your problem but maybe it could help.

Comment: I put up a test page with a dumbed-down version of my code. Thanks for the suggestions. I'll check that IP address thing out.